# Comparing fields to find none matches

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

```
SELECT Left([PTC Import].[ZipCode],5) AS Expr1, [PTC Import].[Country], [ZipCodeDatabase_STANDARD].[ZipCode]
FROM [PTC Import] 
LEFT JOIN [ZipCodeDatabase_STANDARD].[ZipCode] ON Expr1 = [ZipCodeDatabase_STANDARD].[ZipCode]
WHERE ((([ZipCodeDatabase_STANDARD].[ZipCode]) Is Null) AND (([PTC Import].[Country])="USA"
FROM [PTC Import], ZipCodeDatabase_STANDARD;
```

Ok what I have here is my attempt to compare the ZipCode field from my import to our ZipCode database to validate and make sure it is in fact a valid zip code. I would like this query to display any records that do not match a valid zip code where the country is USA.

I am currently getting a syntax error in JOIN statement error message.

I have the ZipCode db linked from another Access db if that would affect anything.

Comment: "Syntax error in JOIN operation" is the message I am getting

Comment: ah yeh the last line you dont need it any more, already answered below i beleive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line

```
FROM [PTC Import], ZipCodeDatabase_STANDARD;
```

shouldn't be there. I think you had an inner join and forgot to remove it:

Then you have an error in your LEFT JOIN with [ZipCodeDatabase_STANDARD], where you are using an alias you defined in FROM. You should use Left(i.[ZipCode],5), since the alias isn't defined yet.

Additionally, i added an alias for each table to make it easier to read.

It should be:

```
SELECT Left(i.[ZipCode],5) AS Expr1, 
       i.[Country], 
       zs.[ZipCode]
FROM [PTC Import] i 
LEFT JOIN [ZipCodeDatabase_STANDARD] zs ON Left(i.[ZipCode],5) = zs.[ZipCode]
WHERE zs.[ZipCode] Is Null AND i.[Country])="USA";
```

Comment: I have no syntax error anymore but I am not getting the records to show even when the zip code is invalid

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that i understand, but try adding `zs.[ZipCode] Is Null` to the ON clause instead of the WHERE.

Comment: Same. Still not displaying the records with invalid zip codes that I made invalid to test.

Comment: Try adding the table structures and some sample data in [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) to see if i can help you further

Answer (score 2):

Your `LEFT JOIN` seems to be trying to join a table with a field.

```sql
FROM [PTC Import] 
LEFT JOIN [ZipCodeDatabase_STANDARD].[ZipCode]
```

Join a table to another table instead.  Perhaps this is what you need.

```sql
FROM [PTC Import] 
LEFT JOIN [ZipCodeDatabase_STANDARD]
```

For the join's `ON` clause, I think you want ...

```sql
ON [PTC Import].[ZipCode] = [ZipCodeDatabase_STANDARD].[ZipCode]
```

And then eliminate the second `FROM` clause.

If you have Access' query designer available, use that to create your query.  At least set up the join from the designer because it knows how to create joins which keep the db engine happy.